# Can some help me translate this into Korean, please?

Tags: phrase-request

“Don't make a hasty movement. Be like a mountain. Move silently and cautiously.”

It’s by Yi Sun Shin, one of Korea’s greats.

Thank you.

Comment: Googling "勿令妄動 靜重如山" will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original quote is in Classical Chinese, the literary language used in Korea at the time:

> 勿令妄動 靜重如山 (물령망동 정중여산)

Translated to Korean, it would be:

> 가벼이 움직이지 말라, 태산과 같이 무거이 행동하라.